# Draw semicircle chart using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, pie-chart

Is `matplotlib` capable of creating semicircle charts like this:

[image: Five segments in an arc, each in a different color and a text label above it. A line indicating the current value is drawn from the center of the semicircle out to the edge. The number value is below the chart and centered.]

I have tried `matplotlib.pyplot.pie` without success.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like there is a built-in half-circle type in `matplotlib`. However, a workaround can be made based on `matplotlib.pyplot.pie`:

1. Append the total sum of the data and assign white color to it.
2. Overlay a white circle in the center by an [Artist](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/artist_api.html) object ([reference](https://jingwen-z.github.io/data-viz-with-matplotlib-series3-pie-chart/)).

Sample Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data
label = ["A", "B", "C"]
val = [1,2,3]

# append data and assign color
label.append("")
val.append(sum(val))  # 50% blank
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'white']

# plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6),dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.pie(val, labels=label, colors=colors)
ax.add_artist(plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.6, color='white'))
fig.show()
```

Output:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found a method to solve this problem. We can use `wedges[-1].set_visible(False)` to hide the last part of the circle chart

Comment: @guotree how do we define wedges? is it imported from patches or anything else

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data
label = ["A", "B", "C"]
val = [1,2,3]

# append data and assign color
label.append("")
val.append(sum(val))  # 50% blank
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'k']

# plot
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6),dpi=100)

wedges, labels=plt.pie(val, wedgeprops=dict(width=0.4,edgecolor='w'),labels=label, colors=colors)
# I tried this method
wedges[-1].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

**Output**:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtDFT.jpg)